# FilePicker.io security - Is API Key required when using policy and signed policy

Tags: filepicker.io

I have a security question regarding using the Pick Widget.

I had assumed that if I supplied the data-fp-signature and data-fp-policy
I would not need to supply the API key.

When I don't supply the API Key I get the following JavaScript Error "Uncaught FilepickerException: API Key not found"

I have verified that my generated policy and signed policy match the filepicker.io test harness.

Answer (score 1):

The API key is necessary for letting Filepicker.io who you are - the policy and signature are ways of verifying that you are who you say you ware, but you have to indicate who you are in the first place with your API key (for instance, so that we can look up your security secret and verify that the signature hash is correct)